# what is 'nogroup' group's purpose

Tags: permissions, group

When I list al groups I see one called 'nogroup'. What is this for? Is it supposed to be least privileged one or something?  I'm using ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but I found this interesting, http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`nogroup` is the group analog to the `nobody` user.  It is used for unprivileged processes so that even if something goes wrong the process does not have the permissions to cause any serious damage to an important user or group.

Comment: Is there any sense in nobody/nogroup? I once found that ntpd in OpenSuSE was running as "nobody" - so if someone gets nobody he can kill my ntpd...

Comment: @Nils You are correct.  The `nobody` user paradigm only works for a single service.  The recommended practice is moving towards running each process as a separate user.

Answer (score 3):

Debian's [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups) for `nogroup` explains it as:

> nogroup (user: nobody): Daemons that need not own any files run as user nobody and group nogroup. Thus, no files on a system should be owned by this user or group.

Answer (score 0):

No an answer for this question, but a relevant information.

I had folders and files owned by `nobody nogroup`.

I wanted to know the ID of `nobody nogroup`, then I found that the `ls` command has the option `-n` to see the IDs instead of names.

So `ls -ln` showed me the IDs:

```
65534 65534
```